# Oracle SQL Developer: how do I make the Home and End keys behave?

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

When I'm working in a Worksheet in Oracle SQL Developer, the `Home` and `End` keys jump me to the beginning and end of the whole Worksheet respectively, not the beginning and end of the current line. Is there a way to change this behavior?

Answer (score 3):

Set your shourcut behaviours in Tools -> Preferences -> Shortcut Keys

source :
http://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2012/11/keyboard-shortcuts-in-oracle-sql-developer/